# Unable to deliver worldwide text message from aws lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-regions

I am trying to send OTP from my AWS Lambda function hosted in AP-South-1 (i.e. Mumbai) region. I am using a worldwide text-messaging feature of SNS for this. As the "AP-South-1" region does not support worldwide text-messaging feature, I am sending the SNSClient's region endpoint as "APNortheast1" (i.e. Tokyo) region as it supports worldwide text-messaging.

Now, I have given my lambda function administrator privilege (by attaching role with administrator policy). But, still, it doesn't seem to be working (not delivering the message to my mobile). I am not getting any exception while executing the function and I am also getting the "TransactionID" for that SMS. In the SNS console, the SMS is showing as failed. So, I have enabled the cloudwatch log for it. The log I am getting is below-

```
{ 
   "notification": {
        "messageId": "8cba93de-b794-577d-99be-c1ba5d5d21dd",
        "timestamp": "2017-10-21 06:26:17.946"
   },
   "delivery": {
        "destination": "+91XXXXXXXXXX",
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "providerResponse": "Internal error",
        "dwellTimeMs": 79 
   },
   "status": "FAILURE" 
}
```

Now, here is the irony- this is actually a new account where I am migrating (manually) the resources from another account. In this older account, I have the exact same setup, but it seems to be delivering the message properly to my mobile. For your information, my Lambda function is written in the .net core and I am trying to deliver the SMS to an Indian mobile number.

Comment: Although the error message does not suggest that this is the problem, have you exceeded the new account's spending limit for SMS?  Have you tried sending messages directly from the SNS console?  Have you tried the SNS console in other regions, such as us-east-1?

Comment: Hello @Michael-sqlbot I have tried to send SMS from the console directly in "APNortheast1" region. But it's not got delivered even from the console. This current account is very new and so, no way it had exceeded the spending limit. But now when I tried with "USWest2" it works from both console and code. But it's not working from any Asia pacific regions. This kind of solved my problem. But, without knowing why its not working from AP regions, makes me feel uncomfortable for making the code to production. Please let me know if you have something in your mind.

Comment: If it works from one region and not from another, that suggests a problem exists in the region that you are using, that AWS support needs to be aware of, so you may want to post on the [official forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=72) or open a support case if you have a support agreement.  Either way, capture the logs and include the passing and failing message IDs so that support can find the specific events.  Note also that unless you took steps to increase it, your account will have a default spending limit of only US $1.  It could still be related to this.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am not sure that there is some problem in the region(s) itself. As my old account is still active and configured, I can still sent messages from Asia pacific region(s) using lambda functions in my old account. But, somehow new account's lambda functions are unable to do so. Anyway, I will log this issue. Also I have updated my account's spending limit. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Be sure you reduce the problem to it's simplest form.  If it doesn't work in the SNS console, the fact that it doesn't work from Lambda is not really relevant, and may distract from the real nature of the problem.  Please come back and let us know what you found.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47858093/174777

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2017, Amazon SNS supports SMS messaging [in the following regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html):

- US East (N. Virginia)
- US West (Oregon)
- EU (Ireland)
- Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
- Asia Pacific (Singapore)
- Asia Pacific (Sydney)

A quick way to send an SMS is with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws sns publish --phone-number 9112345678 --message foo --region ap-southeast-2
```

This fails when using `ap-south-1`, because SMS is not supported in that region.

Your Lambda code can send the message via another region, but you will need to **create your SNS client object in a different region**.

Comment: Small note for users trying to send messages this way: make sure to update your local `aws` cli as the `--phone-number` option is (relatively speaking) new (I was running version 1.10.34 which did not have it). `aws` upgrade instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html). Short version: `pip install awscli --upgrade --user`