# Unable to deliver TEXT message from sns console aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to send text message from SNS console from the supported region list:
US East (N. Virginia),US West (Oregon)
EU (Ireland)
Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
Asia Pacific (Singapore)

I tried with all above region but got the below response:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "2deeb7d5-fc63-5353-962d-e56549411e4b",
        "timestamp": "2017-12-17 18:09:38.321"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "destination": "+919860694302",
        "smsType": "Promotional",
        "providerResponse": "Internal error",
        "dwellTimeMs": 41
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

I'm using the free tier feature and i have created a new account and IAM user.
I tried to find the probable cause for this issue on aws forums,but didn't get any relevant answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending a message via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to test the process:

```
aws sns publish --phone-number +91234567890 --message foo
```

This will help you determine whether the problem is with a particular region, a particular country or a particular recipient.

Comment: I used the AWS CLI interface too and it gave me no error message and i got the message ID,below is the response:
{
    "MessageId": "36489459-386f-58fd-a8b5-c6e86a4d1f97"
}
But still the message is undelivered and the same is happening when i'm using it with AWS java SDK

Comment: Great! So, if the CLI works but your existing code doesn't, then it's a matter of comparing the differences. Feel free to Edit your question to provide more information about how you currently send the message. Maybe it's due to the "Promotional" type? Any other information you have would help.

Comment: The message is not getting delivered from AWS CLI too.I'm getting the message ID from all the the three places : SNS console,AWS CLI,AWS SDK. But the delivery is failing from all places.I can see the internal error from the cloudwatch logs.
It's failing for both promotional and transnational messages

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that the message was undelivered. It might be due to your number, your network, all of India, etc. Try other combinations (different number, a number on a different network) and see if you can get something working. Try it from the Mumbai region too (via `--region ap-south-1`).

Comment: I tried with all possible regions of AWS that support messaging but it's failing for all.

Comment: Did you try a different phone number, that belongs to a different phone network? Looks like the same error as reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46860820/174777